# how to remove the color gradient from the top of ui-button-right in jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have added the padding on top in the home button that in the header. Now I wants to disable the gradient effect from the top of the home button. I actually wants a plain color button. The home button should give a plain color and no top shadow like effects. See the example below

```
<style>
.ui-btn-left{
    padding-top:10px;
}
</style>
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
     <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false" data-direction="reverse"  data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-left">home</a>
    <h1>Resultaten</h1>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/1404/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the jQuery mobile modifies the HTML code by creating 1 inner span called `.ui-btn-inner`, this span wraps 2 other spans called `.ui-btn-text` and `.ui-icon`. So when you set `padding-top` on the `a` element, the whole inner span `.ui-btn-inner` is pulled down and the style is still effected making the ugly gradient above the text. So instead of setting `padding-top` on the `a` element, you have to set it on the `.ui-btn-inner`. However it's not such simple, the `.ui-icon` is positioned absolutely causing problem to align the button text and button icon. So I've tried setting the position to `static`, floating it to the left, adjusting the margin accordingly... Here is the CSS:

```
#header-right-button .ui-btn-inner {
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-top:13px;    
}
#header-right-button .ui-icon {    
  position:static;       
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:5px;
}
#header-right-button {
  height:80px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3EgrW/1406/)

If you want to remove the gradient border, try setting the `border:none` on the `.ui-btn-inner`. Here is the [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3EgrW/1407/) for this. It's fortunate that, if you just want this we have a much simpler code because you can just set the `padding-top` on the `#header-right-button`:

```
#header-right-button {
  padding-top:10px;    
  height:80px;   
}
#header-right-button > .ui-btn-inner {
  border:none;
}
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3EgrW/1408/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where exactly in the css your button is getting its colour (gradient) from. In the example you've posted, the ui-button is getting its styling from the jquery.mobile.css file - you would need to overwrite that styling with your own.
source - element inspector